# R: select all subject who have >5 entries for a variable

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe (>1 million entries) for ±50.000 different subjects. All subjects have between 1-±20 entries, depending on how long they were in the study.
I want to make a new dataframe including only the subjects with >=5 measurements and then take all of them (so if a subject has 10 measurements I want all 10, if someone has 5 I want all five). There is a lot of missing data, I don't want the rows with value == NA

Example of what my data looks like:

```
subjid    value  
1         20
1         30
1         NA
1         20
1         40
1         45
2         20
2         30
3         NA
4         15
4         100
4         NA
4         100
4         130
4         150
```

What I need as output

```
subjid    value  
1         20
1         30
1         20
1         40
1         45
4         15
4         100
4         100
4         130
4         150
```

I'm relatively new to R, if you need more information to answer please ask!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `dplyr` approach. First group by id and filter those with at least 5 values. After that remove the `NA`. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% group_by(subjid) %>% filter(n()>=5) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
# Groups:   subjid [2]
   subjid value
    <int> <int>
 1      1    20
 2      1    30
 3      1    20
 4      1    40
 5      1    45
 6      4    15
 7      4   100
 8      4   100
 9      4   130
10      4   150
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(subjid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), value = c(20L, 30L, NA, 20L, 40L, 45L, 
20L, 30L, NA, 15L, 100L, NA, 100L, 130L, 150L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select groups which has more than 5 non-NA value.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(subjid) %>% filter(sum(!is.na(value)) >= 5 & !is.na(value))

#   subjid value
#    <int> <int>
# 1      1    20
# 2      1    30
# 3      1    20
# 4      1    40
# 5      1    45
# 6      4    15
# 7      4   100
# 8      4   100
# 9      4   130
#10      4   150
```

This can also be written in base R :

```
subset(df, !is.na(value) & ave(!is.na(value), subjid, FUN = sum)  >= 5)
```

as well as `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[!is.na(value) & sum(!is.na(value)) >= 5], subjid]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
> subs
# A tibble: 15 x 2
   subjid value
    <dbl> <dbl>
 1      1    20
 2      1    30
 3      1    NA
 4      1    20
 5      1    40
 6      1    45
 7      2    20
 8      2    30
 9      3    NA
10      4    15
11      4   100
12      4    NA
13      4   100
14      4   130
15      4   150
> subs %>% na.omit() %>% group_by(subjid) %>% filter(n() > 4) %>% ungroup()
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   subjid value
    <dbl> <dbl>
 1      1    20
 2      1    30
 3      1    20
 4      1    40
 5      1    45
 6      4    15
 7      4   100
 8      4   100
 9      4   130
10      4   150
>
```

If you want to remove NA values after grouping you can use this:

```
subs %>% group_by(subjid) %>% filter(n() >4) %>% ungroup() %>% na.omit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In two steps, using a `tidyverse` approach, first collect the id of the subjects with 5 or more non-NA values:

```
subjects_to_take <- test %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(subjid) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  filter(n >= 5)
```

Then extract the non-NA values:

```
new_test <- test %>%
  filter(subjid %in% subjects_to_take$subjid) %>%
  na.omit()
```